# Manual folder watcher for transmission?

Tags: shell-script, transmission

For some reason transmission's `watch-dir` functionality doesn't work for me (I tried a few "solutions" I found but nothing worked). So I made myself a script to supply for that (note that I put this script in my `crontab` to run hourly, so I needed to add fullpaths for everything):

```
#!/bin/bash

prefix='/home/user'
folder=$prefix'/path/to/watched/dir'
cd $folder

count=$(ls -1 *.torrent 2>/dev/null | wc -l)
if [ $count != 0 ];then
    echo $count torrents files found
    for torrent in '*.torrent'; do
        echo adding $torrent
        transmission-remote -n 'transmission:transmission' -a $folder/"$torrent"
        rm $folder/$torrent
    done
else
    echo no torrents found
fi
```

What I got with this script is that it works if there is only 1 torrent file. But if there is 2 or more, then only 1 of them is added, all of them are removed and the line `echo adding $torrent` shows all torrents.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Use `inotify-wait`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect that the line

```
for torrent in '*.torrent'; do
```

is not expanding to a list of files because you've [enclosed it in quotes](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/67757/wildcards-inside-quotes). It expands later each time `$torrent` is used, but this passes all of your files to transmission at once.

Rewrite this line as

```
for torrent in *.torrent; do
```

I also recommend using `nullglob`. See [for loop glob mishaps](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/293647/for-loop-glob-mishaps).

Also, `inotify-wait` can be used to trigger a shell script when a file is created in a directory.

Comment: thanks, i removed quotes and now it works fine. Could you expand more in how to use `inotify-wait`?, a quick search and i couldn't see how to monitor only `*.torrent` creations, but i now that it should be with `-e create` option.

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/323901/how-to-use-inotifywait-to-watch-a-directory-for-creation-of-files-of-a-specific